# How can I edit the Blog Content Definition in Orchard CMS to add an image to the blog's home page?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

It seems like it would be a common desire to have an image associated with an Orchard CMS blog.

How can (or should?) I modify the Content Definition of type Blog to add an image to the blog's home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to content definition, edit the blog content type, and add a media library picker field.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I am new to Orchard if you cannot tell. :) Would you mind giving me a hint as to how I would go about setting how the media item gets displayed? Right now it is positioned below the list of blogs, but I would like it on top.

Comment: Your next steps should be to read about placement.info, which will help you reorder how parts and fields get rendered. Then you'll want to learn about shapes, templates, and alternates.